# Does a CPU or GPU mine better on the RandomX algorithm for Monero mining?

Tags: mining, cpu-mining, gpu-mining, random-x

Was RandomX made specifically for CPUs or GPUs for mining? I know it's ASIC resistant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RandomX is designed to run efficiently on general purpose hardware, e.g. CPUs and to some extent, GPUs.

Quoting the project [README](https://github.com/tevador/RandomX#randomx):

> RandomX is a proof-of-work (PoW) algorithm that is optimized for general-purpose CPUs. RandomX uses random code execution (hence the name) together with several memory-hard techniques to minimize the efficiency advantage of specialized hardware.

And quoting the section on [GPUs](https://github.com/tevador/RandomX#gpu-performance):

> Note that GPUs are at a disadvantage when running RandomX since the algorithm was designed to be efficient on CPUs.

Note that whilst GPU mining wont be as efficient as CPU mining, GPU mining is still effective on RandomX, it just wont have the same advantage it currently has over CPU mining with the current algorithm, CryptonightR.